# IBM Websphere MQ - UI Login Issue

Tags: ubuntu, ibm-mq

I have installed the IBM MQ version `mqadv_dev901_linux_x86-64.tar.gz` in my ubuntu system by following the link: `https://hub.docker.com/r/ibmcom/mq/~/dockerfile/` which has `MQSeriesWeb-9.0.1-0.x86_64.rpm` also installed. I am able to open the UI but not able to Login into it. Checked the user id and password available in file at following location but unable to login:
`/opt/mqm/web/mq/samp/configuration/basic_registry.xml`.
Default `Userid` and password is admin and admin respectively.
Another `userid` and password is reader and reader also.

Please suggest how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

The user is "admin" but the password should be "passw0rd"

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps listed in the below link.That should help you.I tried on windows and it worked for me.The same should apply for linux as well

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.adm.doc/q127580_.htm

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. I have followed the same what is available in this link. But didn't work for me. I am trying and will update soon on this.